# NetworkX: plotting a graph in a for loop returns the wrong graph

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, networkx

I am working with a regular network (grid) that I create as:

```
import networkx as nx
N=100
def graph_creating(N):
    G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
    pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dictionary of all positions
return G, pos
```

I have two ways of iterating the code.  In both I remove nodes from the network and attempt to draw it.  Depending on whether I create the network initially or within the loop, I get a different behavior when I plot it.

**My problem:** I want to plot the grid **after stage 1** and **after stage 2**, so to make comparisons with the unaltered grid/graph. I fail to do it properly because:

- If the original grid is created **outside** the `for` loop, I correctly get the first plots but later plots are empty as the graph is never restored back to its unaltered statu;
- If the original grid is created **inside** the `for` loop, I always end up having the unaltered grid plotted, as if the removal had no effect on it.

Where else should the graph-creating block be placed, in order to be able to plot the graph right after stage 1 and 2?

**version 1** the graph is created outside the `for` loop:

```
G, pos = graph_creating(N)
nodelist = G.nodes()
for counter in range(5):
    G1 = nodelist[2*counter:2*counter+1]
    G.remove_nodes_from(G1)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos)
    figurename = 'file{0}.png'.format(counter)
    plt.savefig(figurename)

    G2=nodelist[2*counter+1:2*counter+2]
    G.remove_nodes_from(G2)
    nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=pos)
    #it's not clear from your original question if you save this figure or not
```

**Result:** only the first iteration produces correct plots. Later plots are empty as the graph is never restored back to its unaltered status.

**version 2**  the graph is created inside the `for` loop:

```
for counter in range(5):
    G, pos = graph_creating(N)
    nodelist = G.nodes()
    G1 = nodelist[2*counter:2*counter+1]
    G.remove_nodes_from(G1)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos)
    figurename = 'file{0}.png'.format(counter)
    plt.savefig(figurename)

    G2=nodelist[2*counter+1:2*counter+2]
    G.remove_nodes_from(G2)
    nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=pos)
    #it's not clear from your original question if you save this figure or not
```

**Result:** the calls to `nx.draw_networkx` result in the unaltered graph being plotted for each iteration. I wonder if the problem is in the way I call that function, as it always plots the graph with no failed nodes. **Why do I have this plotting problem?**.

Comment: I am not sure I fully get it, but if your problem is that the original graph is altered, why not simply create a copy when entering each loop so that the original graph is not altered with `tmp_G = org_G.copy()`. Also, I do not see any difference in your code between **situation 1** and **situation 2**

Comment: The difference between sit 1 and 2 is that in sit 1 the graph is created outside the loop, while in sit 2 it is created inside. In the first case I get a situation where the graph is taken intact and applied the `csv` files one by one without refreshing the graph, leading to a complete failure of the network after the second iteration. In sit 2 the graph is refreshed at each iteration but it is plotted as if no failure happened (but failure happens).

Comment: The problem is that, with each iteration, the graph must be plotted after stage 1 and stage 2. With the new iteration, the graph must enter the loop unaltered so that I can evaluate what happens during the failure stages. The `tmp_G = org_G.copy()` returns `NameError: name 'org_G' is not defined`.

Comment: org_G is just a name indicating that I mean the original graph. In you code you should use `tmp_G = G.copy()` And then apply the changes of removing nodes to tmp_G and also plot it to see the changes and if you want to compare it to the original use G

Comment: I tried to make myself clearer in the answer

Comment: I've edited your question to try to create a MCVE.  Please read over it, and if you agree with it leave as is (though probably you should edit it a bit to make sure it's in agreement with your pbolem).  If you disagree, roll it back.  But - most importantly, look at what I did to create that example because it's going to be useful in helping get good answers elsewhere, and fewer down votes.

Comment: If you copy and paste a block of your code into a question, then every line of that code should be essential to reproducing your issue, and it should not be possible to simplify anything.  Unless you think it's relevant that you're using .csv files including that is noise that makes it difficult for us to figure out what's going on.  Unless `with_labels=False` is essential to what you're observing, it's just noise.  Is `dpi=1000,  node_size=10, bbox=tight` relevant?  If you don't know you haven't done enough debugging to ask us to spend time on this.  If they aren't relevant, strip them out.

Comment: By the time you've stripped the information down to the version that I've presented you would probably realize that in the second version it's not plotting the original graph repeatedly.  It's plotting the graph with G1 removed.  If your code is plotting the original graph, it's because of lines you've left out - which you would discover in creating a *complete* example.

Comment: More general comments on coding style 

- I've simplified the way you're handling the positions.  This may be useful more generally in your code or it may not.  It certainly helps us read and understand your problem.

- You should be defining functions.  As one example, the graph creation shouldn't be sitting in the middle of the rest of your code.  It should be it's own function as I've done.  This makes it easier to debug, and easier to maintain, and easier to explain, and perhaps more significantly for a researcher - easier to adapt to new questions.

Comment: @Joel Thank you very much for your efforts. I failed to post an MCVE because of the fact that my code is rather long, I am not used to handling it, and I also got confused a lot. In addition, I am so new to Python that sometimes it is hard for me to figure out how to render things. Then again, thank you.

Comment: @Joel But one thing must be pointed out, as highlighted by the answer of Abdallah Sobehy: I was not getting the proper graph representation not because of the lines that were not included in my original post but because of the fact that I was calling `nx.draw_network(G)`, and this line kept referring to the **original, unaltered** `G` rather than the modified versions that I intended to plot. I hope to have rendered things  clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Do your graph creating block outside the for loop.
- Inside the for-loop create a copy of the graph using `tmp_G = G.copy()`
- when using `draw_netwokx` or `remove_nodes_from` use **tmp_G** instead of **G**
- When you want to compare the altered graphs to the original one call the draw_networkx function using graph **G**

Comment: It worked! This must have something to do with `networkx`, as I knew the original graph had to be created outside the loop. In particular, I think that `nx.draw_network` is not very flexible: as `G` changes, it should plot it the way it is, e.g. it should **follow** the changes of `G`. But it looks like it does not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani "as G changes, it should plot it the way it is, e.g. it should follow the changes of G"...  What do you mean by this?  Each time you tell it to draw `G`, it draws the current version of `G`.

Comment: Well, if it did, I wouldn't have needed to make a copy of it. This is an interesting point: why does the script flow work if I use `H=G.copy()`? And why does it not if I use just `G`?

Comment: because you are making changes to G in the older version so you can not get the unaltered version anymore. So, you create a temporary copy to manipulate freely

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani "Well, if it did, I wouldn't have needed to make a copy of it.".  No.  You're misunderstanding what you're asking it to plot.  It's plotting the current version of `G`.  You've modified `G` a lot - each time through the loop you were modifying it more.  The copy that Abdallah helped you create is allowing you to leave the original `G` alone, so that you start fresh each time.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I wanted. I had in mind the idea that `G` was updated  going from unaltered status to stage 1 and then to stage 2...